# Using dictionary instead of the if and else statement python without a function

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to convert this `if` and `else` code to a dictionary.

```
SomeVar = SomeVar1["This returns an integer 1-any-number dynamically"]
# Here is the if/else variant
If SomeVar == 1:
    SomeVar = "String 1"
elif SomeVar == 2:
    SomeVar = "String 2"
# and so on


#Insted I want to use a dictionary to accomplish this
TypeDic = {
  "1": "String1"
  "2": "String2"
  "3": "String3"
 }
```

I want to still be able to access it as I would the if-statement. I know it still takes me back to not doing this at all and just using the `SomeVar` variable as it is, but I'll like to learn more about dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors and you want the keys of the dict to be of type `int` not `str`.

Do this:

```py
d = {
  1: "String1",
  2: "String2",
  3: "String3",
 }

some_var = ...
some_string = d[some_var]
```

---

**Example:**

```py
d = {
  1: "String1",
  2: "String2",
  3: "String3",
 }

some_var = 2
some_string = d[some_var]
print(some_string)
```

Output

```
String2
```

Comment: Thank you that was quick and understandable

Comment: @Atenuu Happy to help. Don't forget to upvote/accept if it helped :)